# Do While Loop invalid procedure/loops not working

Tags: excel, vba

Current problem is the = dir statements at the bottom of DFile loop causes an error. I do not understand why one of the = dir statements causes an issue but the other does not?

```
Sub for_each_workbook()

Dim folderpath As String, Dfile As String
Dim sourcepath As String, sourcefile As String
Dim DWorkbook As Workbook
Dim SWorkbook As Workbook
Dim DWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim SWorksheet As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim DateRange As Range, cell As Range
Dim Date_lastrow As Long
folderpath = ‘filepath1
Dfile = Dir(folderpath & "*.xlsx")
    Do While Len(Dfile) > 0
        DoEvents
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set DWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(folderpath & Dfile, UpdateLinks:=0) 'set DWorkbook as recently opened Destination Workbook
        Set DWorksheet = DWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        sourcepath = ‘filepath2
        sourcefile = Dir(sourcepath & "*.xlsx")

        Do While Len(sourcefile) > 0
            On Error GoTo 0
            Set SWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(sourcepath & "\" & sourcefile, UpdateLinks:=0) 'set SWorkbook to recently opened Source workbook
            Set SWorksheet = SWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            If SWorksheet.Range("B2").Value = DWorksheet.Range("B5").Value Then 'check if source sheet is for same system as destination workbook
                    DWorkbook.Activate
                    For Each ws In Worksheets 'for each worksheet in correct source workbook, do the following:
                    Date_lastrow = Range("a999").End(xlUp).Row 'find last row
                    Set DateRange = Range("A8:A" & Date_lastrow)
                        'do vlookup
                    Next ws
                Else: SWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
            End If
            DoEvents
            sourcefile = Dir 'not working?
            Loop
        DoEvents
        DWorkbook.Close savechanges:=True
        Dfile = Dir 'not working?
    Loop

End Sub
```

The excel macro should do the following:

1. open an excel file in folder 1
2. Open an excel file in folder 2
3. confirm that folder 2's excel file is the correct one to use (via checking a cell value)
4. Performing a task (if correct) in each Worksheet
5. loop through files in folder 2 until the task is complete
6. move onto next file in folder 1

I haven't been able to test the majority of the above due to the current issues but it seems to function until the end of the loops.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Dir() more than once in a nested loop like this - you must run each Dir() as separate loops (each Dir() must complete before you start another).  Try running the first dir and add the results to a collection, then loop over that collection and use Dir on the stored values from the collection.

Comment: Thank you, this explains why I am getting confused. First time attempting nested loops, as it shows... Thanks again